# Применить одну функцию к 3-ем разным input'ам

Tags: javascript

Прошу вашей помощи, так как только учу JS. У меня есть функция, которая рассчитывает цену для первого товара, в зависимости от количества данного товара. Так вот, как используя одну и ту же функцию сделать тоже самое со всеми тремя товарами? В учет берем и то, что каждый товар имеет свою цену, так как на данный момент работает только с первым товаром, даже если ввожу данные в другие поля, расчет идет все равно только для первого товара.

```
<div class="services">
            <div class="service-block">
                <div class="image-service">
                    <img src="css/images/icons/car-engine-png-hd-ferrari-gtc4lussot-engine-ferrari-of-washington-512.png">
                </div>
                <div class="service-name">
                    <h1>Замена двигателя</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="block-quantity">
                    <input onblur="totalPrice()" type="number" id="quantity" class="input-quantity" value="1"><label for="quantity" class="label-quantity">Количество:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="delete">
                    <a class="delete-link">Удалить</a>
                </div>
                <div class="price">
                    <p class="price-text" id="result">545 руб.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="service-block">
                <div class="image-service">
                    <img src="css/images/icons/car-engine-png-hd-ferrari-gtc4lussot-engine-ferrari-of-washington-512.png">
                </div>
                <div class="service-name">
                    <h1>Диагностика автомобиля</h1>
                </div>
                 <div class="block-quantity">
                    <input onblur="totalPrice()" type="number" id="quantity" class="input-quantity" value="1"><label for="quantity" class="label-quantity">Количество:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="delete">
                    <a class="delete-link">Удалить</a>
                </div>
                <div class="price">
                    <p class="price-text" id="result2">345 руб.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="service-block">
                <div class="image-service">
                    <img src="css/images/icons/car-engine-png-hd-ferrari-gtc4lussot-engine-ferrari-of-washington-512.png">
                </div>
                <div class="service-name">
                    <h1>Покраска</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="block-quantity">
                    <input onblur="totalPrice()" type="number" id="quantity" class="input-quantity" value="1"><label for="quantity" class="label-quantity">Количество:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="delete">
                    <a class="delete-link">Удалить</a>
                </div>
                <div class="price">
                    <p class="price-text" id="result">600 руб.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Конкретно сама функция:

```
function totalPrice() {
    let quantityNumbers = document.getElementsByClassName('input-quantity');
    let price = 545;

    for (let i = 0; i < quantityNumbers.length; i++) {
        if (parseInt(quantityNumbers[i].value)) {
            price *= parseInt(quantityNumbers[i].value);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = price + ' руб.';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let services = document.querySelector('.services');

services.addEventListener('input', amountOfMoney);

function amountOfMoney (e){
  let price = e.target.closest('.service-block').querySelector('.price-text').innerHTML;
  console.log( price )

  let count = e.target.value;
  console.log( count )
  let arr = price.split(' ');

  let sum = arr[0] * count;
  console.clear();
  console.log( sum )

}

services.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  let target = e.target;

  if( target.tagName != 'a'.toUpperCase() ){
    return 
  }

  let number = target.closest('.service-block').querySelector('.input-quantity').value

  if( number > 0 ){
    target.closest('.service-block').querySelector('.input-quantity').value = 0;
  }
  
})
```

```html
<div class="services">
            <div class="service-block">
                <div class="image-service">
                    <img src="css/images/icons/car-engine-png-hd-ferrari-gtc4lussot-engine-ferrari-of-washington-512.png">
                </div>
                <div class="service-name">
                    <h1>Замена двигателя</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="block-quantity">
                    <input  type="number" id="quantity" class="input-quantity" value="0"><label for="quantity" class="label-quantity">Количество1:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="delete">
                    <a class="delete-link">Удалить</a>
                </div>
                <div class="price">
                    <p class="price-text" id="result1">545 руб.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="service-block">
                <div class="image-service">
                    <img src="css/images/icons/car-engine-png-hd-ferrari-gtc4lussot-engine-ferrari-of-washington-512.png">
                </div>
                <div class="service-name">
                    <h1>Диагностика автомобиля</h1>
                </div>
                 <div class="block-quantity">
                    <input  type="number" id="quantity" class="input-quantity" value="0"><label for="quantity" class="label-quantity">Количество2:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="delete">
                    <a class="delete-link">Удалить</a>
                </div>
                <div class="price">
                    <p class="price-text" id="result2">345 руб.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="service-block">
                <div class="image-service">
                    <img src="css/images/icons/car-engine-png-hd-ferrari-gtc4lussot-engine-ferrari-of-washington-512.png">
                </div>
                <div class="service-name">
                    <h1>Покраска</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="block-quantity">
                    <input  type="number" id="quantity" class="input-quantity" value="0"><label for="quantity" class="label-quantity">Количество3:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="delete">
                    <a class="delete-link">Удалить</a>
                </div>
                <div class="price">
                    <p class="price-text" id="result3">600 руб.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

1. проблема возникла как подсчитать конкретный инпут через цикл ?
2. Правильно применил к HTML - структуре два обработчика ?

Comment: у меня была конкретно с тем, что не знал как правильно изменить функцию так, чтобы я мог применить ее к любому блоку в html и она считала цену в зависимости от начальной цены товара, то есть чтобы я не писал для каждого блока новую функцию с разными значениями переменных)

Answer (score 2):

```
<input onblur="totalPrice(this)" ...

function totalPrice(el) {
  ...
  el.closest(".service-block").querySelector(".price-text").innerHTML = price + ' руб.';
}
```